# Html.dropdownlist does not display the default/selected value in the dropdown field

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a table with various rows and each row corresponds to an ID. For every row, I have EDIT option which when selected should enable the user to look at the default values corresponding to that ID in the '**Edit.chtml**' fields and there by update it by erasing the default values and typing in the new entry and saving it.

In '**Edit.chtml**', I have a field for "MANAGERS" that I need to populate with a dropdownlist of names with default/selected value displayed corresponding to the ID of the row where Edit operation is selected from the table. 
I am using viewBag but **my problem is the dropdownlist is always displaying the first item in the list and not the selected value.**  Please see the code below.

```
Controller:
 //
        // GET: /ManagersNAMES/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            using (var db = new InpEntities())
            {
                var list_managers = (from x in db.TABLE_MANAGERS
                                        select new TABLE_MANAGERSDTO
                                        {
                                            ID = x.ID,
                                            NAME = x.NAME,
                                        }).OrderBy(w => w.NAME).ToList();

                ViewBag.managers = new SelectList(list_managers, "ID", "NAME", id);

                return View();
            }
        }

        public class TABLE_MANAGERSDTO
        {
            public string NAME { get; set; }
            public int ID { get; set; }
        }

        //
        // POST: /ManagersNAMES/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, TABLE_INSTITUTES dp)
        {
            try
            {

                using (var db = new InpEntities())
                {

                    TABLE_INSTITUTES tmp = (TABLE_INSTITUTES)db.TABLE_INSTITUTES.Where(f => f.ID == id).First();
                    tmp.MANAGER = dp.MANAGER;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

View: '**Edit.chtml**'

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>

    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight:bold">MANAGER</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("dp.MANAGER", (SelectList)ViewBag.managers)
    </div>

    <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the selected id within the controller like this:

```
var list_managers =  list_managers.Select(x => new
                          {
                              Value = x.ID.ToString(),
                              Text = x.Name
                          })
                          .ToList();

ViewBag.managers = new SelectList(list_managers, "ID", "NAME", id);
```

And change your view to:

```
@Html.DropDownList("dpMANAGER", (SelectList)ViewBag.managers)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its complaining about Value = x.ID "Cannot implicitly convert int to string" I tried to cast it but does not work

Comment: Sorry, I've not tested it as I don't have the full code. Please try the toString() as above.

Comment: Thanks I tried that. Thats seems to be okay. However, I have this issue - "Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'"

Comment: Please try the above, I'm sure we'll get there in the end. :D

Comment: :) I tried sorry to say that I got this error - 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: I'll check it out, I usually used strongly typed views with a model defined. Give me a few mins.

Comment: Please give that a try now.

Comment: Oh no! I am using viewBag approach and I cannot go back. Any workaround using viewBag? Thanks for your time on this! Please let me know with same code for viewBag. I posted it in my question already

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31533/discussion-between-hutchonoid-and-archer)

Comment: hutchonoid: No its not working, I am unable to use SelectListItem in view

Comment: Thank you! Your approach worked for me. The reason I was having issue later was I was passing a wrong value to selectedvalue which was not matching with any of the IDs.

Answer (score 2):

Just wrote  `@Html.DropDownList("dp.MANAGER", ViewBag.managers)` without selectlist, becouse its already in type of SelectList.

And write `ViewBag.managers = new SelectList(list_managers, "ID", "NAME");` like this

Comment: Thanks Timur for your response! I had to use SelectList in dropdownlist as it is throwing an error